# Python hangman game,doesnt work

Tags: python

I am trying to develop a Hangman game in Python, and I am stuck figuring out why the correctly guessed letters are not being remembered by the program.

For example, if the entered letter is in the word "hello", python recognizes a match but when it prompts for another letter to be entered, it forgets the `updt_list` (list which has the entered letters).

If anyone would be kind to have a look I would be really grateful.

```
import time


def pick_a_word():

    word = "hello"
    return word

def guess_a_letter():
    aletter = input("Please input one letter at a time:\n")
    no_letters= len(aletter)
    if no_letters > 1:
        print("You inputed more than one letter! Don't forget- one at a time.\nLets try again..")
        time.sleep(2)
        return guess_a_letter()
    else:
        return aletter


def blankLIST(aword):
    blankList = len(aword) * "_"
    return list(blankList)

def check(aletter,aword,blankLIST):

    updt_list= blankLIST(aword)

    which_letter= aword.index(aletter)

    updt_list[which_letter] = aletter

    return updt_list


def engine():

    guess=guess_a_letter()
    wordtoguess=pick_a_word()
    if guess in wordtoguess:
        print("\n")
        print("The letter is in the word")
        print(check(guess,wordtoguess,blankLIST))

        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("\n")
        print("The letter is not in the word")

        time.sleep(1)




def repeat():
    x = 0
    while x <= 5:
        lifes= 6- x
        print("You have",lifes," attempts left")

        engine()

        x = x

repeat()
```

Comment: `it forgets the updt_list` It forcibly remembers a newly created value in `check`, to be returned, printed and - forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that this is very inelegant and there will be problems if you keep on guessing the letter 'l' in this case... I didn't have more time to spend on it but it should be enough to push you a bit forward. It remembers the player's guesses now and the user can win the game. My apologies...

```
    import time


    def pick_a_word():

        word = "hello"
        return word

    def guess_a_letter():
        #aletter = input("Please input one letter at a time:\n")
        aletter = 'l'
        no_letters= len(aletter)
        if no_letters > 1:
            print("You inputed more than one letter! Don't forget- one at a time.\nLets try again..")
            time.sleep(2)
            return guess_a_letter()
        else:
            return aletter


    def buildWordLIST(aword):
        blankList = len(aword) * "_"
        return list(blankList)

    def check(aletter,aword,updt_list, wordIndex=0):

        which_letter= aword.index(aletter, wordIndex)

        if updt_list[which_letter] != "_" and ((wordIndex + 1) < len(aword)):
            wordIndex = which_letter + 1
            check(aletter,aword,updt_list, wordIndex)

        updt_list[which_letter] = aletter

        return updt_list


    def engine(mistakes, updt_list, correctGuesses):

        youWinFlag = False

        guess=guess_a_letter()
        wordtoguess=pick_a_word()
        if guess in wordtoguess:
            print("\n")
            print("The letter is in the word")
            updt_list = check(guess,wordtoguess,updt_list)
            print updt_list
            correctGuesses += 1
            if correctGuesses == len(wordtoguess):
                print("YOU GUESSED THE WORD!")
                youWinFlag = True


            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            print("\n")
            print("The letter is not in the word")
            mistakes += 1
            time.sleep(1)

        return mistakes, updt_list, correctGuesses, youWinFlag



    def repeat(updt_list):
        x = 0
        blankLIST = ''
        correctGuesses = 0
        while x <= 5:
            lives= 6- x
            print("You have",lives," attempts left")

            results = engine(x, updt_list, correctGuesses)
            x = results[0]
            updt_list = results[1]
            correctGuesses = results[2]
            youWinFlag = results[3]
            if youWinFlag:
                x = 6

    def initialize_game():
        wordtoguess=pick_a_word()
        updt_list = buildWordLIST(wordtoguess)
        return updt_list

    updt_list = initialize_game()
    repeat(updt_list)
```